# Can I add Centos or Redhat main repositories to Amazon Linux?

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, amazon-linux

I’m trying to use AWS Cloud 9 for development, however it forces you to use Amazon Linux, instead of my familiar Ubuntu.

The major limitation is the lack of available packages.

Is it possible to add the main CentOS or redhat repos in order to install a normal universe of packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Amazon Linux is its own thing, a fork that looks significantly different than modern Red Hat/CentOS.  [What Linux distribution is the Amazon Linux AMI based on?](https://serverfault.com/q/798427/241174)

Worth a shot to try to install if the only RPM available is an EL one. But you probably will have to compile and package things yourself.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for Cloud 9? This used to be Ubuntu based, and now it’s Amazon Linux only- which is a miserable experience.

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with Cloud9. The documentation suggests that remote SSH environments are possible where you bring your own Python + Node.js. I cannot comment on the limitations there, and that's a new question besides.